# web URL information to apache spark in web app

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am currently are trying to retrieve information from the EPA into our web app, which needs to utilize ibm bluemix and apache spark. The information that we are gathering from the EPA is this:

https://aqs.epa.gov/api and ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface/

But not only are we gathering historical data, we also want to update the data by inserting new data every hour into the web app. Hence concerning this I have a few questions:

1) Do we need to open a hdfs to store all the data? Or could we just retrieve the data by its URL and store it in a dataframe? IBM bluemix said it would provide 5 GB of storage, so how would one utilize that to store the historical data and store updated data per hour?

2) If we are going to update the data per hour by inserting new data into the data storage / data frame, should we still use spark streaming? If yes, how would we use spark streaming for URL data? A lot of resources I see online is only useful if one has an hdfs / formal database.

What we are doing currently is that we import the URLs through pandas:

```
url = "https://aqs.epa.gov/api/rawData?user=sogun3@gmail.com&pw=baycrane57&format=JSON&param=44201&bdate=20110501&edate=20110501&state=37&county=063"
import urllib2
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print content
```

However, if we use this method, it means that spark needs to be running 24-7 to ensure that the most updated data is utilized. How does one configure spark to run 24-7? Or is there a better method to process all the data and put them nicely in a dataframe so that the data could be accessed easily later?

Also, in a web app, can one still use iPython for data processing? Or is iPython just for interacting with the data and understanding the data experimentally?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have options ;-) If you need to read the source EPA data and then process it before you use it in your web app, then you can use the spark service to ETL (Extract Transform Load) the source data from EPA web site, manipulate or wrangle the data into the shape and size you want, and then save it into a storage service like [Bluemix Object Storage](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/index.html). You web app would then read the data in the format you want directly from object storage.  However, if the source EPA data is largely in a format you want to use in the web app, then you most certainly can create RDDs directly from web site and pull in the data as and when you need it. These datasets look small from my quick peek, so I don't think you need to worry about spark pulling it directly into memory for you to work on it; i.e. no need to try to store it locally with spark in the bluemix service cluster. Besides, there is no HDFS currently provided by the spark service; so as mentioned earlier, you would use an external storage service. re: "IBM bluemix said it would provide 5 GB of storage", that is intended for storing your personal and 3rd-party spark libraries and such.

re: "spark needs to be running 24-7".  The spark service runs 24x7. Your spark code running on the service will run for as long as you program it to run ;-)

IPython (or Jupyter notebooks) is intended as a REPL for the web. So, yes, interactive. In your case, you can certainly write your spark code in an IPython notebook and have that run for as long as necessary, pulling and processing the EPA data for the web app, storing it in say object storage. The web app can then pull the data it needs from object storage.  It is said that in the future APIs we will provided for the spark service, at which point your web app could talk directly to the spark service; in the meantime, you can certainly make something work with notebooks.